# Better practices with subdivisions surface modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm learning blender with help of the wiki, and other articles around the web(including blenderguru and blender artists).

I'm trying to make a model for a character that I've sketched, but Im having some problens with the junctions of his neck, this makes me wonder what's the best practice for creating a junction such as this one.

First try render result
[image: First try render result]

Mesh of the first try
[image: Mesh of the first try]

Second try with subdivision modifier
[image: Second try with subdivision modifier]

Any light on this matter?

Comment: Could you upload your .blend using http://pasteall.org/blend/  or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to have a low poly character, the easiest way would be to select the lower vertices of the neck

[image]

and move them down into the chest.

[image]

A better way would be do have a connected mesh with good topology (this one was created by Make Human):

[image]

Comment: It is connected I have deleted the entire neck and did a bridge edge loop on the second try, yet I'm still getting those results.

Comment: It must be as you said, the topology, which I suck, since I'm new on 3D modeling.

I'll do your first suggestion, but will it imply in something having the body parts separated? 
Well, for working with vector animation, it's good to make the body parts separated at last. But I have no

Comment: You could select a part of the mesh and separate it with 'P' (Separate/Selection in Edit Mode) this would create another object. I'm used to start several approaches from scratch ;-)

Comment: Yes, I've done it, thanks! I rigged it and all. But I still need some more practice. I'll make some other characters like that with all the differents approachs possible to see which one I feel more comfortable.
Thanks!

Comment: The often you do it the faster you get ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your neck is not actually connected to the body. Try deleting the shoulder face, then select all the base neck vertices plus the 4 shoulder ones and hit "f" to create a face. Then try the subdivision again.